# Estimate the number of typos there are in a book, based on two editors' finds

Tags: recreational-mathematics, estimation

This is one question from an interview I have just taken:

> Suppose there is a book full of typos. *Tom* and *Jerry* found $x$ and $y$
> typos throughout the book, respectively. There are $z$ typos that they
> both found.
>
> The question is *how to estimate the total number of typos
> in this book?*

I find this question quite interesting but do not know how to deal with it. Can anyone give me a hint on this? Thanks!

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion. But this question is pretty stupid (as it often is the case with these tests).

Comment: Suppose I found $1$ typo and you found $1$ typo and we both found the same typo. How many typos did we find? What if I found another one? What if you then too found another one? How many typos would there be?

Comment: $x+y-z$ by principle of exclusion inclusion

Comment: Since this was an interview question, I wonder if "read the book" was an appropriate response, since Tom and Jerry are clearly incompetent.  Maybe "hire an editor".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume Tom finds a typo with probability $p$ and Jerry with probability $q$. Let $T$ be the number of typos.

Then Tom finds $x=Tp$ typos, Jerry finds $y=Tq$ and the number of typos they expect to both find is $z=Tpq$. Solving for $p$, we get $p=\frac{z}{y}$. Then $T\approx\frac{x}{p}=\frac{xy}{z}$.

This assumes $z>0$, and it assumes the odds of the two finding a typo are independent (which is an unlikely assumption, but it might be a "good enough" model.)

Comment: Yes! Exactly! the answer is `xy/z`. Do you think that there is some intuitions behind the eqution `xy/z`?

Comment: Other than that my argument above, no.

Comment: In any event, the assumption of independence is probably a big problem. Still, the reasoning might be good for other types of sampling.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the intended solution.  But the number of problems with it isn't few.  For example, it also assumes that every typo has the same probability of being found (very unlikely for any incapable of finding all typos).

Comment: Agreed. This is a back-of-the-envelope approximation, but it is the type that comes up in interviews when interviewers are trying to be clever. Most clever would be to give this answer and then discuss all the problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the minimum number of typos possible?  That is when they both found the same typos.  For instance, suppose $x=3, y=4$.  The least possible number of typos found would be when they overlap as much as possible, so that $z=3$ and all together they found 4 typos.

What is the maximum number of typos possible?  That occurs when they found none of the same typos, so again if $x=3, y=4$ then we want $z=0$ so that they found $7$ typos together.

In general the relationship is that the number of typos they've found is $x+y-z$.  To maximize this for a fixed $x$ and $y$, you minimize $z$.  To minimize this, you maximize $z$.

---

So OK, now you know how many typos they found in the book together:  $x+y-z$.  If you want to estimate the total number of typos in the book, supposing that perhaps they both missed some number of typos, then you'll need to somehow quantify how many typos they might have overlooked.  There are probably many ways to do this but one would be to suppose that for every $m$ typos they found, there were $n$ typos they didn't find.  There probably isn't just one correct pair of numbers to use for this, but one plausible guess might be: Suppose that for Tom it's $x:(y-z)$ and suppose for Jerry it's $y:(x-z)$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question properly:

Let $A$ be the set of typos Tom found, $B$ the set of typos Jerry found and $C$ the set of typos they both found. Note that: $C = A \bigcap B$

The number of typos is: $card(A \bigcup B) = card(A) + card(B) - card(A \bigcap B) = card(A) + card(B) - card(C) = x + y - z$.

Comment: Why do you assume that they have found every typo together?

Comment: Where do I do that?

Comment: You assume that the total number of typos is $card(A\cup B)$. I guess the question is more of a probabilistic one.

Comment: Oh I see. You meant to ask me why do I assume equal probabilities. But then, in such a situation, how can we possibly know the probabilities? I think that my assumption is more practical, no?

Comment: No sorry, what I mean is: What if Tom only found half of the typos, and Jerry found zero? Your calculations definitely make sense if we knew that every typo has been found in the end, but if some typos were unnoticed by both, we can only estimate the amount of typos.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks.